# How do I get the weather_manager in pyowm?

Tags: python

The following code worked without a problem before.

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM(owm_api_key)
manager = owm.weather_manager()
```

But now it instead outputs the error AttributeError: 'OWM25' object has no attribute 'weather_manager'

Following the code recipe in the docs, it suggests that you should do the following:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
owm = OWM(owm_api_key)
manager = owm.weather_manager()
```

But that just gives the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyowm.owm'

Considering that my code worked previously, I'm guessing that it is just some update but I can't find the right way to do it.

Comment: can you `pip freeze` and display what version of `pyowm` you are running?  it is common practice to "pin" your versions in a `requirements.txt` to avoid upgrade errors like this.  https://medium.com/@boscacci/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e

Comment: In my requirements.txt I originally had `pyowm==2.10.0` but I changed it to `pyowm==3.0.0`, thinking that that is how you update packages. Having run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` the program worked again and I had `pyowm==2.10.0` in my requirements.txt. I then updated pyowm the right way and now my code works with pyowm 3.0.0